# I thought this was a C7 type connector, but it has this significant difference

Tags: connector, identification

One can find this type of connector in many small personal appliances at home, usually related to those that are rechargeable. The connector appears eerily similar to a C7, but it is NOT a figure-eight as it NOT "flippable" and is connectable only one way. However, you can see that it is also NOT polarized. Given all this, what type is it? See pictures (multiple) attached.

[image: Photo of connector]

Comment: You'll find all the common ones on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320.

Comment: If its a shaver or something similar, it's probably not a mains connector, but a manufacturers custom DC connector,

Comment: If this should be considered a "manufacturer's custom DC connector," you should know that i was not able to post the remaining SEVEN pictures of identical connections on other small appliances, EVERY ONE of them using the same input DC voltage as this. They all INTERCHANGEABLY use EITHER a 120 VAC to 1.5VDC plug-in transformer OR an ordinary USB to plug into the pictured connection. If this is "custom," geez.... it is incredibly popular....

Comment: @TomCarpenter I agree - it looks similar to my Phillips shaver - doesnt look polarised (any markings) on the outside but it only goes in one way. My shaver is Li-Ion though and the plug is sort of blocky so I assume its a SMPS to low DC levels, yet still locked to one orientation.